# When calling DocumentSummaryInformation.setHeadingPair what should the value look like

Tags: java, apache-poi, openxml

I'm trying to copy properties from a docx to doc (OOXML -> POI).
The method

```
DocumentSummaryInformation.setHeadingPair
```

Receives a byte[], but I don't know what the data should look like.
Couldn't find any examples online.
Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [DocumentSummaryInformationSummary source code](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hpsf/DocumentSummaryInformation.java)

```
/**
 * <p>Sets the heading pair.</p>
 *
 * @param headingPair The heading pair to set.
 */
public void setHeadingPair(final byte[] headingPair)
{
    notYetImplemented("Writing byte arrays ");
}
```

So, I'm not sure why you think you want to set a heading pair, but you're not going to be able to do it anyway!